# iFrame transparent background not working

Tags: html, css, iframe, chatbot, styled-components

I am trying to add a custom chatbot using an iframe and the background to that chatbot is not transparent.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

This is the transparent stlying to the child content:

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  html{
    background-color: transparent;  
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
```

The iFrame in the parent content

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8080/chatbot" 
  allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I would like the chatbot's background to be transparent
Also, I would like to add that I have not set a background anywhere else in the code

Comment: so what is working for you with using this css: `iframe { background-color: transparent; }` ?

Comment: Is allowtransparency obsolete, and never was part of an HTML standard?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I have the same problem on some web sites